# LFS 7.4 chapter 6.7: make: gcc: Command not found

Tags: linux, gcc, lfs

I am (again) trying LFS. The version is 7.4

I am stuck at chapter 6.7, where I must run: `make mrproper` and I get this error: `make: gcc: Command not found`. But the `gcc` is there. I also cannot run `readelf` or `ld`, I get the same error.

After some search on the web I found out that this is something done wrong and that I should start all over again. Well, I started all over and got the same error at the same point. I made more searching and I tried starting from the beginning again, but still I got the same error.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What is in your `$PATH`?  Where are `gcc`, `readelf`, `ld`, etc installed to?

Comment: My PATH `/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/tools/bin` Gcc, readelf and ld are in `/tools/bin/` and if I use the full path `/tools/bin/gcc` I get `bash: /tools/bin/gcc: No such file or directory`. g++ gives the same error. But outside the chroot environment, on the host if I run /tools/bin/gcc I can compile a dummy file.

Comment: Try `ldd /tools/bin/gcc` (in or out of the chroot). If it references anything outside the root you missed a step somewhere.

Comment: I started all over again. Now I just finished the second pass of `gcc`. `ldd` shows this: `linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff011fe000)
        libm.so.6 => /usr/lib/libm.so.6 (0x00007f237da6f000)
        libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f237d6c5000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f237dd72000)`. I guess that this is wrong. But when I run the sanity check om the Page 50 using readelf after compiling a dummy file i get `[Requesting program interpreter: /tools/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]`, that is the expected.

Answer (score 1):

After running the second pass of `gcc`, `ldd` was pointing that `gcc` was using the host libraries. I didn't know how to solve it, so I simply ran the second pass of `gcc` again, but using the `gcc` binary of the last second pass without passing a `CC` variable.

Then ldd started to show that `gcc` was using the stuff under /tools.

But the binaries of `binutils` was also using the host libs, so I made again the second pass of binutils, without the `CC`, `CXX`, `RANLIB` or `AR`. This time it worked, I guess.

Now I am compiling `glibc` inside the chroot environment and so far I had no more problems. I don't know if what I did was right, but it did work.

Comment: I successfully finished the LFS, it is all working now.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue the first and second time I went through LFS. I was using multiple console windows to build multiple packages at the same time because there are a lot of small packages to build.

I started over a third time and decided just to build one package at a time. It took a long time but I got everything to compile correctly and work properly in the chroot environment.

If you run into this problem, you should probably just start over:

```
rm -rf /mnt/lfs/tools/*
```

Then just rebuild all of the packages, one at a time, following all instructions exactly. It is also not recommended to build this inside `VirtualBox` but I was able to get it to work after a couple of tries.