# 6.7 Linux headers `make mrproper` fails in lfs 7.5

Tags: linux, gcc, lfs

I'm building lfs-7.5.

When I run `make mrproper` in chapter **6.7**, it says:

> make: gcc: command not found

and on running `bash /tools/bin/gcc`, it says:

> bash: /tools/bin/gcc: no such file or directory

This is the same problem as [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110184/lfs-7-4-chapter-6-7-make-gcc-command-not-found). Even the information given by the person who asked the question in the comments is same as mine.

He says that he did "**third pass**" of `gcc` in **chapter 5**. If this was the case then the author of LFS would have clearly indicated to us to perform 3 passes. I'm guessing that I'm making a subtle mistake somewhere, but I can't seem to find out where.

According to the support provided by LFS authors, they ask us to redo the whole thing from the beginning. I agree with them, but without knowing where the mistake might have happened we are bound to make the same mistake again (as I did). The output provided by the person who asked the question in the LFS support question matches mine. This is the [link](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.lfs.support/37171).

Another question about the same topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23159786/lfs-bash-tools-bin-gcc-no-such-file-or-directory) did not yield any answers.

Please help.

BTW, when I found out that `gcc` was not linked to the libraries in `/tools/lib` of LFS, I manually created a simlink from `libc.so.6` to `/lib` and `/lib64` under `/mnt/lfs` where I mounted the LFS partition. But when I was executing `make headers_check` in **6.7** (after `make mrproper`), it complained that it didn't find `libz.so` and when I searched in `/tools/lib`, I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know whether the previous answer I submitted is **correct** or not.

I decided to continue doing `LFS-7.5` in `Linux Mint`, where user `lfs` was present in the `sudoers` file. After finishing **Chapter 5**, I again got an error at **Chapter 6.7** `make mrproper`. So, I deleted all folder under `$LFS` except `$LFS/sources` and started from the beginning.

After finishing the 2nd pass of `gcc`, I checked whether the libraries of `gcc` pointed to the ones under `$LFS/tools` or not. But I found out that they were still pointed at `/usr` of host system.

So, I re-built from 1st pass of `gcc` and then everything was fine.

So, after 2nd pass of `gcc`, do:

> ldd `$LFS/tools/bin/$LFS_TGT-gcc`

and if the resulting output points to `/usr`, redo from 1st pass of `gcc`.

At least, this the method I used and immediately after redoing the 1st pass of `gcc` the 2nd time, the output of the above command was pointing to `$LFS/tools/lib`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to successfully execute `make mrproper` and the following commands. I don't really know whether this is really the solution to the above problem. Anyway here it is:

I was using Ubuntu 14.04 and I created **lfs** user as suggested by the LFS-7.5 book. But the problem was that I didn't realize until later, much later, when `chroot`ing into the LFS partition that, lfs user was not in the **sudoers** file.

Ubuntu did (does?) not automatically add the user to the **sudoers** file, probably by design by the Ubuntu people. This might be the reason, I did not try it again on Ubuntu.

I got disheartened and started trying LFS-7.5 in **Linux Mint 16** and it automatically added the user to the **sudoers** file and everything went fine at **Chapter 6.7** while building and installing **linux headers**.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. I checked the dynamic linker used by gcc : `readelf -l /tools/bin/gcc | grep interpreter` and it was not */tools/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2* but */lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2*. So, gcc could not run because this file did not exist. 
The problem came from the gcc Pass2 building step. I did not put the definition of CC, CXX, AR and RANLIB on the same line than the configure command.

I ran

```
CC=$LFS_TGT-gcc
CXX=$LFS_TGT-g++
AR=$LFS_TGT-ar
RANLIB=$LFS_TGT-ranlib
../configure --prefix=/tools ...
```

Instead of

```
CC=$LFS_TGT-gcc \
CXX=$LFS_TGT-g++ \
AR=$LFS_TGT-ar \
RANLIB=$LFS_TGT-ranlib \
../configure --prefix=/tools ...
```

Same problem could apply in binutils pass2 build step. I suppose it is a problem of variable focus.